# How do I enable hardware virtualization on the Designare ex x399?

Tags: bios, virtualization, docker, threadripper

I just completed a new workstation build (Designare EX x399, Threadripper 1950x, gtx 1080ti) and everything works great, except Docker doesn't work because I need to enable hardware assisted virtualization in the BIOS. However, I can't find the option to, or any material related to how I might enable it. Is it possible for this motherboard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go into the BIOS during boot by pressing DEL. Then go to M.I.T -> Ext. CPU core settings and set "SVM mode" to "enabled"

If you happen to change the hardware as I did (from i7 to TR) you have to disable Hyper-V in the Windows settings (search for "Hyper" and then select enable Windows features), reboot, enable it again and reboot again. Then it worked for me. I uninstalled and reinstalled Docker in between but that might not be required.

Comment: Strangely enough it was under M.I.T. -> Advanced Frequency Settings -> Advanced CPU Core Settings. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though